# Problem parsing release apk file created with cordova on android phone

Tags: android, cordova, parsing, package

I am creating an app with Cordova (version 11). Everything works when I run it on an emulator or launch it on my device. However, when I create the release version, the APK file won't install on my device. It says, "There was a problem parsing the package."

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:compileSdkVersion="30" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="11" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" package="com.mpi.calculator" platformBuildVersionCode="30" platformBuildVersionName="11">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.mpi.calculator.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am not sure how to begin solving the issue. I can post additional information as needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try to install the APK file via ADB on a connected phone using `adb install <appfile.apk>`. If this fails please copy the command and its response, edit your question and include it formatted as code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I was able to figure it out and have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So, I will answer my own question here, just in case other people find this page via a web search. The problem I was having was due to the way I was generating the apk file. I was using the command

```
cordova build android --release -- --packageType=apk
```

and this was generating the "app-release-unsigned.apk" file which was giving me the error. After a LOT of online searching, and seeing that everyone was using "build.json" files along with the command

```
cordova build android --release --buildConfig
```

I decided to try that. I created a JSON file with the following format:

```
{
    "android": {
        "debug": {
            "keystore": "./myapp.keystore",
            "storePassword": "*******",
            "alias": "MyApp",
            "password" : "******",
            "keystoreType": "jks"
        },
        "release": {
            "keystore": "./myapp.keystore",
            "storePassword": "******",
            "alias": "MyApp",
            "password" : "******",
            "keystoreType": "jks",
            "packageType": "apk"
        }
    }
}
```

and ran the command and it worked. The "build.json" file needs to be in the root cordova project folder and so does the keystore file.

To generate the "keystore" file, I used the command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA1withRSA -validity 9000
```

It will ask you to type in a password, then re-type in the same password, then enter a bunch of information such as your name, the name of your organization and where it is located. Then it will ask you to enter the password for the "alias", which can be different than the password for the keystore, and then re-enter the "alias" password. Those two passwords are what go into the JSON file above.

I am still not sure yet how to change the name of the release file, but that is not important right now.